# Sencha Touch 2.2.1 not run on IE10

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am a newbie of Sencha.

I use Sencha Architect (Version: 2.2.2 Build: 991) to create the Sencha Touch (2.2.1) application.

But when I deploy and run it on IE10, it does not work, showing blank screen. I open the debug mode (F12), and I see that the browser always auto changes to the Browser mode IE10 Compat View, Document Mode: IE7 standard.

I switch the Browser mode to IE10, the app run again. Is there any config I need to set to run on IE10? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is built for Webkit-based browser (Chrome, Safari)

IE and other browsers like Firefox are not built on Webkit, thus not able to render pages written with Sencha Touch. Even if you can run it this time, there will be elements that cannot be displayed properly, causing the page to have weird look.

Update: sorry for the wrong info. Since 2.2, Sencha Touch provides support to IE 10. So this means your page should be rendered without any problem with IE10. I tried opening up a page created by Sencha Touch 2.2 on my Lumia, it was OK without any problem. I guess IE10 on desktop may have a false detection in your case and try to open the page in IE7 compat mode. On actual device there shouldn't be such issue.

Comment: But on the Sencha Touch 2.2.1 already support for IE10. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/whats_new

Comment: Yeah, I haven't used Sencha Touch for some time. It's great to know that they finally get things work on IE10 as well.